# Security Measures For Banking Information

Tags: encryption

I am creating a site that will allow users to input their banking account number so I can pay them for their services.  I am far from a security expert and would like some insights into the best practices for encrypting this data.

So far I have gathered that at a bare minimum I should have 256 bit encryption with a salt.  What other measures can I take or would that suffice for enough security measures?

Thanks

Comment: Woah woah woah!  Storing sensitive financial information is an absolute minefield.  You seriously need to look into whether it's absolutely required.  If you must store financial information I would strongly urge you to at least consult with a professional who can advise you about the legal and regulatory requirements (federal & state).  Consider looking into a third party which will handle the financial information for you.  There's lots of third party payment processors, that might be a better way of going about this.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably get someone with more security background to actually look over your site to make sure things are properly implemented and to design your security for you.  Building a system that can safely protect banking information requires a lot of different knowledge and, no offense intended, your question itself demonstrates that you likely have very little experience in this regards.

Encryption does not use a salt, it uses an IV.  Salts are used with hashes. Initialization Vectors ensure that different encryptions of the same information result in different cyphertexts (to prevent the same encrypted value from being recognizable as the same). Beyond encryption for the data, you will need a secure account setup, you will need to prevent against sql injection and cross site scripting, you will need to verify a bunch of things about your server environment and the network it is on, you will need to setup intrusion monitoring.

There is a whole slew of things that go well beyond what we can tell you about in sufficient detail on this site in one answer and there are a lot of pitfalls that can occur based on how you write your code specifically.  You really need someone to work with you directly if you are building your own application for this from the ground up.

Comment: No offense taken.  My lack of understanding on the subject is why I came here to at least get a better idea of what lies ahead.  Thanks for your thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a payment processor. They provide encrypted communication (https) between the costumer and the payment processor. Paypal for example uses TLS RSA AES-256 SHA encryption. Compare other providers fees, provisions and reputations to find the best for your needs.

The payment is a very sensitive part in the ordering process. If costumers might loose money, because the payment-gateway you provided them has serious security issues you could easily be taken liable for their damage. So either hire a professional coder or choose a payment processor which I'd recommend.